# Visibility depening on generic DataType

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ModuleType with two inherited ModuleTypes: PayModule and FreeModule.

I also have a TreeView with this ItemSource:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfModules}">
```

In my DataTemplates there are several Expander. One of them should only be visible if the TreeViewItem has the DataType PayModule

```
<Expander Header="{Binding PayModuleItem.Name}"
  Visibility="{Binding PayModuleItem, Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibleConverter}}">
```

This is my TypeToVisibleConverter. It is Type-specific. Is it possible to get a generic converter?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return Visibility.Collapsed;

    if (value is PayModule)
        return Visibility.Visible;

    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

And I want to pass for example the desired type by the ConverterParameter and then cast to it e.g.:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding PayModuleItem.Name}"
   Visibility="{Binding PayModuleItem, Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibleConverter}, 
   ConverterParameter={x:Type my:PayModule}}">
```

-

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return Visibility.Collapsed;

    if (value is typeOf(parameter)
        return Visibility.Visible;

    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value != null && value.GetType() == parameter as Type
        ? Visibility.Visible
        : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

If you also want to be able to check for base classes or interfaces:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var type = parameter as Type;

    return type != null && type.IsInstanceOfType(value)
        ? Visibility.Visible
        : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Type of `parameter` will always be the Type `Type`, simply cast it `(Type)parameter`. Also, since `is (Type)parameter` will no work you can use this:

```
if ((parameter as Type)?.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()) ?? false)
    return Visibility.Visible;
```

Edit:

<s>Just to point out the differences: Clemens' answer is a lot easier and if you only want one specific Type, use that one. Mine will work for inherited types too.</s>

Edit 2:

No longer true, results will be identical now :)

Comment: `typeof(parameter)` won't compile.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I wrote that a bit too literal - I meant the Type of parameter will always be the Type `Type`.

Comment: Except when you don't specify it. Better use `parameter as Type`, which can be null.

Comment: @Clemens Fair enough